# Render HTML in android

Tags: android, html

Render HTML in android

Problem :

My android applicatation accept HTML from server I want to render that HTML
in which all HTML tag like `<SPAN>,<Style>,<Strong>,` will work fine

```
Sample HTML = 
               <p><strong>Social</strong> <u>Work</u></p><p><em>At least</em>
                <span style="color: rgb(155, 187, 89);">
               <span style="color: rgb(127, 96, 0);">1 day</span></span> 
                 <span style="font-size: 28px;">/ month</span></p>
```

what I tried -

```
         1) Html.FromHtml(html); method but it doesnt support all tag
            It work for some tags only (color is not recognise)

         2) Jsoup.parse(html).text() i used from Jsoup lib but
             It gives same result as above 

         3) sp=StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(html) than I used this like
            Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(sp).toString()))  
            Still no expected result
```

Whent I used Html.fromHtml()
Result I get -

```
           Social Work

           At least 1 day / month
```

Result I want-

```
          Social Work

          At least 1 day / month
          (with "1 day" in RED color)
```

If there is any another method to do these or any mistake I did in above method.

Comment: add more details, your question is very unclear. Add sample html which u r getting from server. Mention clearly what u are getting now and what you want. Currently you have mentioned that "It gives same result as above" but it is not highlighted what result u r referring to.

Comment: Thank for your interest my point is HTML.fromHtml() didn't recognize colors it allow tag such as <font color=" " ></font> but  in my case server use    < span style="color: rgb(155, 187, 89);">   this tag so it not showing colors right   and also it doesn't support tags like <Strong> <em> <Style><Span> etc                               so is there any alternative method is there that understand these type of color tag (same like WebView )            and i am not using webview because  its limitations and speed required to load    ---please reply

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to render Html, why don't use a WebView and load the Html on it?

If not, I think it's more reliable to change your response from the server to fit your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i don't want to use web view because its limitation and speed is there any another method thanks

Comment: Html.fromHtml() support font tag but in my case it is not used what i do now

Comment: Mmm it's a bit dirty but have you tried to put the styles into in a style attribute, instead on a <span>?

Comment: My Database on server is already written that contains Thousands of notes in These type of format means using these tags so its not possible thanks again and if you find any solution please send to me

Answer (score 1):

If WebView is too heavyweight for your purpose and your HTML is relatively straightforward, you may want to consider this github project: https://github.com/kobjects/htmlview